# Why apply function did not work on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply, python-applymap

```
ct_data['IM NO'] = ct_data['IM NO'].apply(lambda x: pyffx.Integer(b'dkrya@Jppl1994', length=20).encrypt(int(x)))
```

I am trying to encyrpt here is below head of ct_data

```
 Unnamed: 0      IM NO                                              CT ID
0           0  214281340  x1E5e3ukRyEFRT6SUAF6lg|d543d3d064da465b8576d87
1           1  214281244  -vf6738ee3bedf47e8acf4613034069ab0|aa0d2dac654
2           2  175326863  __g3d877adf9d154637be26d9a0111e1cd6|6FfHZRoiWs
3           3  299631931  __gbe204670ca784a01b7207b42a7e5a5d3|54e2c39cd3
4           4  214282320  773840905c424a10a4a31aba9d6458bb|__g1114a30c6e
```

But I get as below

```
   Unnamed: 0  ...                                              CT ID
0            0  ...  x1E5e3ukRyEFRT6SUAF6lg|d543d3d064da465b8576d87
1            1  ...  aa0d2dac654d4154bf7c09f73faeaf62|-vf6738ee3bed
2            2  ...  6FfHZRoiWs2VO02Pruk07A|__g3d877adf9d154637be26
3            3  ...  54e2c39cd35044ffbd9c0918d07923dc|__gbe204670ca
4            4  ...  __g1114a30c6ea548a2a83d5a51718ff0fd|773840905c
5            5  ...  9e6eb976075b4b189ae7dde42b67ca3d|WgpKucd28IcdE
```

IM NO columns header name and its value should be 20 digit encrpted ,
Normally encryption is done as below

```
import pyffx
strEncrypt = pyffx.Integer(b'dkrya@Jppl1994', length=20)
strEncrptVal = strEncrypt.encrypt(int('9digit IM No'))
```

ct_data.iloc[:, 1]) displays below thing

```
0     214281340
1     214281244
2     175326863
3     299631931
4     214282320
5     214279026
```

Comment: Could this be a simple display problem? What shows `ct_data.iloc[:, 1]`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It displays IM No column please see , I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment but it contains formatted data.

It is probably a mere display problem. With the initial sample of you dataframe, I have executed your command and printed its returned values:

```
print(ct_data['IM NO'].apply(lambda x: pyffx.Integer(b'dkrya@Jppl1994', length=20).encrypt(int(x))))

0    88741194526272080902
1     2665012251053580165
2    18983388112345132770
3    85666027666173191357
4    78253063863998100367
Name: IM NO, dtype: object
```

So it is correctly executed. Let us go one step further:

```
ct_data['IM NO'] = ct_data['IM NO'].apply(lambda x: pyffx.Integer(b'dkrya@Jppl1994', length=20).encrypt(int(x)))
print(ct_data['IM NO'])

0    88741194526272080902
1     2665012251053580165
2    18983388112345132770
3    85666027666173191357
4    78253063863998100367
Name: IM NO, dtype: object
```

Again...

That means that your command was successfull, but as the `IM NO` column is now larger, you system can no more display all the columns and it displays the first and las ones, with ellipses (`...`) in the middle.